# Can I use regexes within datetime.strptime formats?

Tags: python, datetime

I have string values that contain a trailing time stamp. I thought I could use strptime **with** a regex pattern to extract those.

Like:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from datetime import datetime
# this here works
input_with_ts = "20170410_1133"
print(datetime.strptime(input_with_ts, '%Y%m%d_%H%M'))
# but this is how things really look like
input_with_ts = "foo_bar_D31_848_20170410_1133"
print(datetime.strptime(input_with_ts, 'foo_bar_.*_.*_%Y%m%d_%H%M'))
```

Gives:

```
2017-04-10 11:33:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(datetime.strptime(input_with_ts, 'foo_bar_.*_.*_%Y%m%d_%H%M'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'foo_bar_D31_848_20170410_1133' does not match format 'foo_bar_.*_.*_%Y%m%d_%H%M'
```

Simply wondering: is that even possible - putting a regex pattern into that format string? If not, what is the straight canonical way to get me there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't, only fixed text (so literals) and date-time components are supported.

Just extract the datetime portion first; you can use a regex for *that task* of course. Not that that is needed *in your example*, because the datetime portion is a fixed-width chunk of text at the end:

```
datetime.strptime(input_with_ts[-13:], '%Y%m%d_%H%M')
```