# Regex to match current date in a particular format

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, date, datetime

I have a date format like - yyyymmdd. I basically need to get current date from a regex expression.
Example of date format - 20191211 (for 11th December 2019)
Currently I am using the following regex - ([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))

The code I am using -

```
prefix_regex = "([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))"
now = datetime.now()
date_after_match = now.strftime(prefix_regex)
print (date_after_match)
```

Output - ([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))

I know this is possible if instead of the regex I simply use "%Y%m%d" like -

```
prefix_regex = "%Y%m%d"
now = datetime.now()
date_after_match = now.strftime(prefix_regex)
print (date_after_match)
```

Output - 20191211. This is the desired output from the regex expression.

But, I need to use a regex. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not with strftime - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371940/can-i-use-regexes-within-datetime-strptime-formats . Why do you want to use regex if you already have a datetime object?

Comment: @CDJB I have to use a regex. Is there any other way other than using strftime?

Comment: If you want to validate whether or not the parsed datetime object is within bounds, why don't you do that using comparison operators?

Comment: @OliverW. I have an input which will be in the given date format. I need to match the input with the regex to see if the date is the current date or not.Is it possible with comparison operators?

Comment: IIUC: `datetime.strptime("20190124", "%Y%m%d") == datetime.now().date()`?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me using re :

```py
import re
datestr='20191211'
print(re.findall(pattern="\d"*8, string=datestr)[0])
```